# Samba on Red Hat 7.3 installation

Tags: rhel, yum, samba

Working on **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3** (Maipo)

`yum list installed | grep samba
samba-client-libs.x86_64             4.4.4-9.el7             @rhel-7-server-rpms
samba-common.noarch                  4.4.4-9.el7             @rhel-7-server-rpms
samba-common-libs.x86_64             4.4.4-9.el7             @rhel-7-server-rpms
samba-common-tools.x86_64            4.4.4-9.el7             @rhel-7-server-rpms
samba-libs.x86_64                    4.4.4-9.el7             @rhel-7-server-rpms`

However:

```
$ service smb status
$ Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  smb.service
  Unit smb.service could not be found.


$ which samba
$ /usr/bin/which: no samba in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)


$ which smbd    
$ /usr/bin/which: no smbd in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

Is samba installed or not on my system?

Does the system not beeing activated (through subscription manager) have anything to do with samba not loading (although the pacakages seem to be installed)?

Comment: Try `which smbd`

Comment: updated with your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my installation i have this :

```
yum list installed | grep samba

samba.x86_64                      4.4.4-9.el7                          
samba-client-libs.x86_64          4.4.4-9.el7                          
samba-common.noarch               4.4.4-9.el7                          
samba-common-libs.x86_64          4.4.4-9.el7                          
samba-common-tools.x86_64         4.4.4-9.el7                          
samba-libs.x86_64                 4.4.4-9.el7
```

I think you need to install `samba.x86_64`.

Comment: yep, that seems to be the problem. thanks.

Comment: you're the most welcome

Answer (score 0):

To check if any package is installed or not, use this command

```
rpm -q samba
```

here -q : query

It will tell whether your package is installed or not.
If not, then install by following command -

```
yum -y install samba
```